# Refactor simple codes into 4 functions and ask a return value to main()

Tags: c#, function

Can I use below codes to refactor into 4 functions (i.e area of square, perimeter of rt triangle, area of square, and perimeter of square), and ask at least 1 function to return a value to Main()? If yes can anyone give me a hint on how to do it? I am learning C# on my own and trying to do it from last three days but failed.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double tribase = 9;
        double triwidth = 6;
        double trihypotenuse = Math.Sqrt((tribase * tribase) + (triwidth * triwidth));
        double triarea = 0.5 * (tribase * triwidth);
        double triperimeter = tribase + triwidth + trihypotenuse;
        Console.WriteLine("Area of right triangle = {0}\nPerimeter of rigth triangle = {1}\n", triarea, triperimeter);

        double squareside = 8;
        double squarearea = squareside * squareside;
        double squareperimeter = 4 * squareside;
        Console.WriteLine("Area of square = {0}\nPerimeter of square = {1}\n",  squarearea, squareperimeter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Highlight lines you want to go into a separate function, right-click -> Refactor -> Extract Method.  Then watch Visual Studio do the magic.

Answer (score 7):

A basic function in C# is written like this:

```
static ReturnType Name(ParamType1 paramname1, ParamType2 paramname2)
{
    // Code
    return someValue;
}
```

Where `ReturnType` is the type of the return value (e.g. `double` in your case), `Name` is the name of the function (e.g. `GetSquareArea`), `ParamTypeN` is the type of a parameter for the function, and `paramnameN` is the name of that parameter. And finally in place of `someValue` you'll use an expression or variable with the value you want to return.

Since I suspect this is a homework exercise, I'll only do the area of a square function. You'll have to do the other three from there.

```
static double GetSquareArea(double side)
{
    double area = side * side;
    return area;
}
```

And to use this in your existing code:

```
double squarearea = GetSquareArea(squareside);
```

Note how you have to provide a value for the `side` parameter. In this case the values comes from the `squareside` variable. And note how the result of the function is stored in the `squarearea` variable.

---

To give you an overview, this is what your code would look like with that function in it. Now you add the other three.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double tribase = 9;
        double triwidth = 6;
        double trihypotenuse = Math.Sqrt((tribase * tribase) + (triwidth * triwidth));
        double triarea = 0.5 * (tribase * triwidth);
        double triperimeter = tribase + triwidth + trihypotenuse;
        Console.WriteLine("Area of right triangle = {0}\nPerimeter of rigth triangle = {1}\n", triarea, triperimeter);

        double squareside = 8;
        double squarearea = GetSquareArea(squareside);  // <--
        double squareperimeter = 4 * squareside;
        Console.WriteLine("Area of square = {0}\nPerimeter of square = {1}\n",  squarearea, squareperimeter);
    }

    static double GetSquareArea(double side)
    {
        double area = side * side;
        return area;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for an answer for a noob without spoon-feeding